# How can I add the message in front before the OK?

Tags: c

I want to add a message in front of each ok from the input file, for example, something like this:
[image]

However, I'm getting not quite getting it I'm just getting the OK:

[image]

How can I get the message and then the OK?

Input File:

E201022011101F

P

PBCBCBC

Q7

Q66666676666

Q76767

M84E2010201F

M27PBC

This is the correct code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int foo(char* s) {
int valid = 1;
int len = strlen(s);
if (len < 3)
    return 0;
int i = 0;
if (s[i] == 'E') {
    i++;
    if (s[i] == '0' || s[i] == '1' || s[i] == '2')
    {
        while (s[i] == '0' || s[i] == '1' || s[i] == '2')
            i++;
        if (s[i] != 'F' || i+1!=len)
            valid = 0;
    }
    else
        valid = 0;
}
else
    valid = 0;
return valid;
}
int eep(char* s) {
int valid = 1;
int len = strlen(s);
if (len < 1 || len == 2)
    return 0;
if (len == 1 && s[0] == 'P')
    return 1;
int i = 0;
if (s[i] == 'P') {
    i++;
    while ((i < len) && s[i] == 'B' && s[i + 1] == 'C')
        i+=2;
    if (i==len)
        valid = 1;
    else
        valid = 0;
}
else
    valid = 0;
return valid;
}
int op(char* s) {
int valid = 1;
int len = strlen(s);
if (len < 2 )
    return 0;
int i = 0;
int count = 0;
if (s[i] == 'Q') {
    i++;
    if (s[i] == '6' || s[i] == '7') {
        while (s[i] == '6' || s[i] == '7') {
            if (s[i] == '7')
                count++;
            i++;
        }
        if (i == len)
            valid = 1;
        else
            valid = 0;
    }
    else
        valid = 0;
}
else
    valid = 0;
if ((valid==1) && (count == 0 || count % 2 != 0))
    valid = 1;
else
    valid = 0;
return valid;
}
int ork(char* s) {
int valid = 1;
int len = strlen(s);
if (len < 4)
    return 0;
int i;
if (s[0] == 'M' && (s[1] >= '0' && s[1] <= '9') && (s[2] >= '0' && s[2] <= '9')) {
    char* ss = malloc((len - 2) * sizeof(char));
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 3; i < len; i++) {
        ss[j] = s[i];
        j++;
    }
    ss[j] = 0;
    valid = foo(ss); 
    if (valid != 1)
        valid = eep(ss);
    free(ss);
}
else
    valid = 0;
return valid;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
FILE* fp = NULL;
char* buff = NULL;
size_t len = 0;

if (argc > 1)
{
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can not open %s for reading.\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
}
else
    fp = stdin;
int valid;
while (getline(&buff, &len, fp) != -1)
{
    buff[strlen(buff) - 1] = '\0';
    if (foo(buff) == 1)
        valid = 1;
    else if (eep(buff) == 1)
        valid = 1;
    else if (op(buff) == 1)
        valid = 1;
    else if (ork(buff) == 1)
        valid = 1;
    else
        valid = 0;
    if (valid == 1)
        printf("OK\n");
    else
        printf("FAIL\n");

}
free(buff); 

buff = NULL; 
len = 0;

return(0);
```

}

Comment: Please, reformat the code, so it is legible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use printf("%s OK\n", buff) to replace the line printf("OK\n");

So the codes should be:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>




int foo(char* s) {
int valid = 1;
int len = strlen(s);
if (len < 3)
    return 0;
int i = 0;
if (s[i] == 'E') {
    i++;
    if (s[i] == '0' || s[i] == '1' || s[i] == '2')
    {
        while (s[i] == '0' || s[i] == '1' || s[i] == '2')
            i++;
        if (s[i] != 'F' || i+1!=len)
            valid = 0;
    }
    else
        valid = 0;
}
else
    valid = 0;
return valid;
}

int eep(char* s) {
int valid = 1;
int len = strlen(s);
if (len < 1 || len == 2)
    return 0;
if (len == 1 && s[0] == 'P')
    return 1;
int i = 0;
if (s[i] == 'P') {
    i++;
    while ((i < len) && s[i] == 'B' && s[i + 1] == 'C')
        i+=2;
    if (i==len)
        valid = 1;
    else
        valid = 0;
}
else
    valid = 0;
return valid;
}

int op(char* s) {
    
int valid = 1;
int len = strlen(s);
if (len < 2 )
    return 0;
int i = 0;
int count = 0;
if (s[i] == 'Q') {
    i++;
    if (s[i] == '6' || s[i] == '7') {
        while (s[i] == '6' || s[i] == '7') {
            if (s[i] == '7')
                count++;
            i++;
        }
        if (i == len)
            valid = 1;
        else
            valid = 0;
    }
    else
        valid = 0;
}
else
    valid = 0;
if ((valid==1) && (count == 0 || count % 2 != 0))
    valid = 1;
else
    valid = 0;
return valid;
}
int ork(char* s) {
int valid = 1;
int len = strlen(s);
if (len < 4)
    return 0;
int i;
if (s[0] == 'M' && (s[1] >= '0' && s[1] <= '9') && (s[2] >= '0' && s[2] <= '9')) {
    char* ss = malloc((len - 2) * sizeof(char));
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 3; i < len; i++) {
        ss[j] = s[i];
        j++;
    }
    ss[j] = 0;
    valid = foo(ss); 
    if (valid != 1)
        valid = eep(ss);
    free(ss);
}
else
    valid = 0;
return valid;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
FILE* fp = NULL;
char* buff = NULL;
size_t len = 0;

if (argc > 1)
{
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can not open %s for reading.\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
}
else
    fp = stdin;
int valid;
while (getline(&buff, &len, fp) != -1)
{
    buff[strlen(buff) - 1] = '\0';
    if (foo(buff) == 1)
        valid = 1;
    else if (eep(buff) == 1)
        valid = 1;
    else if (op(buff) == 1)
        valid = 1;
    else if (ork(buff) == 1)
        valid = 1;
    else
        valid = 0;
    if (valid == 1)
        printf("%s OK\n", buff);
    else
        printf("FAIL\n");

}
free(buff); 

buff = NULL; 
len = 0;

return(0);

}
```